# SwipeView's key handler preempting key handler of a child

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using QtQuick.Controls 2.0 `TabBar` to control a `SwipeView`. By default, `TabBar` and `SwipeView` respond to the left and right arrow keys, using what I assume is an `onPressed` handler.

As far as I can tell, these default key handlers are undocumented.

I need a certain element in my UI to get events for all four arrow keys when and only when it has active focus. Currently it does so through an `onReleased` handler, but whenever the ancestor `SwipeView` responds to a key, the child element does not receive the expected `onReleased` key event.

I don't object to the `SwipeView`'s default behavior, but I want my behavior to take priority. How can I do it?

Comment: Neither TabBar nor SwipeView grab any shortcuts. They do not filter or steal key events from other items or controls. They only handle key events that they receive while being focused, or unhandled key events that propagate from children. If your UI element handles key events and you don't want them to propagate further to parents, make sure to accept the key events. Notice also that many built-in controls, such as buttons and sliders, have "strong" focus policy by default, meaning that they gain focus when clicked, for instance.

Comment: @jpnurmi I thought I had shown myself that it wasn't the `SwipeView` responding to key events, and therefore it must have been the `TabBar`. But when I tried to form an example to present in answer to you, I found that I had fooled myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the `onReleased` handler to `onPressed`. If there was ever a good reason for that handler to be `onReleased` instead of the more commonly used `onPressed`, it is no longer evident.